# SKAudioNode won't play sound

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, xcode7

I have a small game that needs some background music. However I cannot figure out how to make this happen! I've tried using SKAudioNode with this code.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    sprite.xScale = 0.5
    sprite.yScale = 0.5
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    self.addChild(sprite)
    //music
    let music = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "music")
    self.addChild(music)
}
```

I have a Data Set in Assets.xcassets called "music" with only one file in it called "music.mp3". I've tried changing the initialization of the music constant to SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "music.mp3") but that had no effect. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have my doubts that you can use music from the XCAssets file. Instead drag and drop the file into your folder. Then use it.
Secondly, just "music" will not work. It requires an extension!

You can even play music using the SKAction Class also!

```
  [SKAction repeatForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"yourFile.mp3" waitForCompletion:YES]];
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Anytime :) It would be great if you could accept the answer if this helped!